# using $http in an AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to move all my AJAX from an Angular controller into a service.  My code worked fine in the controller, but I can't get the same $http requests to run in the service.  When I run the following code, `Data.tracker` is set to "function started" and then never changes.

```
app.service("Data", function($http) {

this.tracker = "not started";

this.loadHumanReadableNames = function() {
        this.tracker = "function started";
        $http.get('http://proteomics.ysu.edu/secretomes/animal/index.php/api/get_human_readable_names/').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            this.tracker = "ajax successful";
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            this.tracker = "ajax failed";
        });
    };
});

app.controller('GlobalController', function($scope, Data) {

    $scope.Data = Data;

    $scope.initializeData = function () {
        //load human readable names
        Data.loadHumanReadableNames();
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE

MajoB's answer works great.  However, for modularity I generally prefer to handle data processing in my model (service) instead of in my controller.  The problem with the above code is that `this` is not available in the success and error functions.  The following will print "ajax successful":

in the service:

```
app.service("Data", function($http) {

this.tracker = "not started";
var self = this;

this.loadHumanReadableNames = function() {
        this.tracker = "function started";
        $http.get('http://proteomics.ysu.edu/secretomes/animal/index.php/api/get_human_readable_names/').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            self.tracker = "ajax successful";
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            self.tracker = "ajax failed";
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return a promise from your service:

```
this.loadHumanReadableNames = function() {            
        return $http.get('http://proteomics.ysu.edu/secretomes/animal/index.php/api/get_human_readable_names/');            
    };
});
```

controller

```
app.controller('GlobalController', function($scope, Data) {   


    $scope.initializeData = function () {
        //load human readable names
        Data.loadHumanReadableNames().success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });;
    }
});
```

or create a custom promise with [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
    this.loadHumanReadableNames = function() {     
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http.get('http://proteomics.ysu.edu/secretomes/animal/index.php/api/get_human_readable_names/').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve({ data: data, tracker : 'ajax successful' })
       });            


       return deferred.promise;        
    };
```

controller:

```
app.controller('GlobalController', function($scope, Data) {   


        $scope.initializeData = function () {
            //load human readable names
            Data.loadHumanReadableNames().then(function (data) {

            });;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**this** keyword inside **success callback** function refer the local scope not the parent object.
So it won't change . Try to assign with some variable after that you can change that variable inside success callback function

Comment: services/providers are singletons (one sevice instance per application) they do not share any parent scope, they can only access a $rootScope if it is included